# How much slower are devnet transactions vs mainnet?

Tags: anchor, web3.js, anchor-test, anchor-lang

When I run my anchor tests, each RPC within the test script only takes around ~500ms. However, when using the same RPC on my program deployed to devnet, even RPC calls without a UI take around 20-30 seconds to complete. Will this be a concern that I have to worry about when I deploy my dapp to mainnet, or is this problem unique to the devnet? My instructions aren't really that complex, just simply writing some data and transferring tokens. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In my experience, devnet transactions are a lot faster than mainnet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because any answer given will be, at best, a snapshot of the truth at this moment in time, and at worst highly dependent on the particular RPC provider involved in any evaluation of performance.